# Entitiy framework one-to-many mapping with condition

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following structure in my DBMS (mysql):

```
create table tasks
(
    id int auto_increment not null,
        primary key (id),
    name varchar(200) not null,
        unique(name)    
);

create table species
(
    id int auto_increment not null,
        primary key (id),
    id_task int,
        foreign key (id_task) references tasks(id) on delete cascade,
    is_history tinyint not null default 0
);
```

One task can have a current species (when is_history=0) and historical species (when is_history=1).
I created the following classes:

```
public class Specie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public Task ParentTask { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Specie> CurrentSpecies { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Specie> HistSpecies { get; set; }
}
```

What is the correct way to create mapping with code-first to map "CurrentSpecies" and "HistSpecies" into one table "species" with difference in one field "is_history"?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the Species class like this:

```
public class Specie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    public Task ParentTask { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Specie> CurrentSpecies { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Specie> HistSpecies { get; set; }
}
```

If you have to create the Task object and the collections within this object then I would suggest you rethink your design. Essentially the task object should then become the aggregate root.

I would also look at using Fluent Api for complex mapping as it offers some flexibility. You can view that here:

[Fluent Api Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146394/A-Look-at-Fluent-APIs)